# How to create Notifications with custom sound in Android

Tags: android

I have this code in my `PostFragment.java` link on Github below

https://gist.github.com/sayseee/0801ff9d955e333365bbd6a73084db71

In that code i already have a code for `sendToWear()` which works on click

```
//Send a BigTextStyle notification with text contents of the post to Android Wear devices
private void sendToWear() {
    // Intent used to run app on the phone from watch
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, viewIntent, 0);

    // Use BigTextStyle to read long notification
    //NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    //bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    // Use Html.fromHtml() to remove HTML tags
    //bigTextStyle.bigText(Html.fromHtml(content));

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            //.setStyle(bigTextStyle);

    // Load featured image as background image
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(featuredImageUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(160, 160) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource,
                                            GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    builder.setLargeIcon(resource);

                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =
                            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
                    notificationManagerCompat.cancel(id);
                    notificationManagerCompat.notify(id, builder.build());
                }
            });
}
```

Where do I insert the code for Notifications and adding sound along with it for new feeds when i post new content? something like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this,**

Replace `builder` object with,

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.your_custom_sound_file)) ;
```

Comment: Thex @Pramod, I got the code i have above online and it seems to send data to android wearable devices.  True am new to android i want the code for the above and where i can insert it ..You can check the github link above

Comment: Do i add that code to the `private void sendToWear()` or i create a new one?

Comment: You can add this inside `private void sendToWear()`